# Can't edit eclipse.ini file in ubuntu system for adding lombok settings?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, lombok

I want to add following lines to eclipse.ini file in ubuntu system

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

but after adding these lines when I try to save the file, the changes made are not at all saving or reflecting in eclipse.ini file.

How can I over come from the this issue?

ran below command to find the location of eclipse.ini file

```
locate eclipse.ini 
/snap/eclipse/48/eclipse.ini
```

and this command to edit the file

```
sudo -H gedit /snap/eclipse/48/eclipse.ini
```

But no luck, the changes made to this file are not at all saved, showing some permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

the snap file system is mounted readonly, so you could:
1.Copy /snap/eclipse/current/eclipse. ini to somewhere you can edit it. /etc/eclipse.ini ...
2.Edit the arguments you want to update and save the file.
3.Open Menulibre.(apt-get install menulibre)
4.Search for "Eclipse."
5.Click in the Eclipse icon.
6.In the "Command" input, add the --launcher.ini option after the binary path. ...
--launcher.ini /etc/eclipse.ini
7.Click in Menulibre's "Save" button.